# How to plot Data From an Excel File in MATLAB? fplot Please

Tags: matlab, loops, plot

I am trying to plot data from an Excel file. I am reading from the second sheet, which has names of machines (machine numbers, but it needs to be flexible), on the top and then numbers underneath.

```
Machine1
1
2
3
4
5
6
etc.
```

The first row, which has the names, needs to be the name of each graph.

Here is what I have so far. Also, please no advanced functions.

```
clear variables
clc
close all

i = 0;
n = 1;

% All the code to do the first part of the graphing
inputFile = xlsread('machineOutput.xlsx', 'Sheet2');

[rows, cols] = size(inputFile);

for c = 1: cols
    clear tempVar;
    clear tempName;
    count = 0;
    i = 1;
    for r = 1: rows
        if(isnan(inputFile(r, c)) == 1)
            inputFile(r, c) = 0;
        end
        tempVar{n} = inputFile(r, c);
        tempName{i} = inputFile(r, c);
    end
    fplot(tempVar, [-2 2])
    title(tempName)
    grid on
    xlabel('Number of Days')
    ylabel('All machines')
    figure
    xlim tight
    n = n + 1;
end
```

Comment: `fplot` is to plot a function, `plot` plots data. Please describe the problem: does your code produce an error message? does it not produce the right output?

Comment: It does not produce the right output. At least I think. I have not seen what the correct graphs look like, but I would think they would be more choppy than they are.